# Idiomatic Kotlin2JS Gradle setup

Tags: javascript, gradle, kotlin

I want to write a JavaScript library in Kotlin, using Gradle as the build tool with Kotlin as the config language for that, too. In the end I'd like to get a single JS file which can be used as a stand-alone library, i.e. with (all required parts of) the Kotlin library bundled into it.

What would a minimal setup to make this work look like? In particular, how do I get the Kotlin libraries bundled in?

---

Here is what I have so far.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/javascript/getting-started-gradle/getting-started-with-gradle.html
only uses Groovy to configure Gradle. It also uses the `buildscript` in combination with the `apply plugin` statement, where I was under the general impression that this is considered a legacy approach and the `plugins` section would be the preferred way.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#targeting-javascript
has Kotlin scripts. The code snippet for `settings.gradle` doesn't have a switch between Groovy and Kotlin, but it appears to work without modification in my `settings.gradle.kts`. That will create a file `js/build/classes/kotlin/main/${project.name}.js` which looks like this (with `moduleKind = "commonjs"`):

```js
(function (_, Kotlin) { … }(module.exports, require('kotlin')));
```

So I can see it containing the transpiled version of my source code, but it won't run on its own; it will need a copy of the standard library. I can add that as a dependency with

```kotlin
dependencies {
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-js")
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-js")
}
```

but that alone is not enough to make the standard library end up in the output. I guess I might be able to use the [`kotlin` npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kotlin), but I'd prefer to automate combining these sources into one.

I also tried disabling the `noStdlib` setting using

```kotlin
tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinJsCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        noStdlib = false
    }
}
```

which contains a fair bit of guesswork since the examples which do things of this kind tend to use Groovy notation and a `compileKotlin2Js` block which leads to a syntax error if my build script is in Kotlin. So with the above I get a compiler error:

```
w: Unable to find kotlin-stdlib-js.jar in the Kotlin home directory.
Pass either '-no-stdlib' to prevent adding it to the classpath, or
the correct '-kotlin-home'
```

So how do I get that one to use the standard library provided as a dependency? Is this even the right approach?

https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/kotlin-js-configuration-made-simple-ef0e361fcd4 and the https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-frontend-plugin it references describe another kind of plugin to help web development, but again all the examples are Groovy only and I couldn't even get the plugin to resolve. I tried things like

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.frontend").version("0.0.45")
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url = java.net.URI("https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap")
    }
}
```

[Another blog post](https://medium.com/@czuckie/experimenting-with-kotlin2js-and-qunit-gradle-ab2164af695) suggests some [Gist](https://gist.github.com/ElFeesho/617cc58979b1172c7add31c2986fd8c0) with commands that allegedly would extract the JavaScript files from dependencies and put them into my output directory. I can imagine this would work, but I'm not yet willing to accept that this would be the best way to address things, that there is no more stream-lined way of achieving this result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webpack can be used in order to create a single JS containing all dependencies.

https://github.com/eggeral/kotlin-single-js-file-lib shows a complete example

1. Make sure the KotlinJS compiler uses as module system which is understood by webpack.

   ```
   tasks.withType<Kotlin2JsCompile> {
       kotlinOptions {
           moduleKind = "umd"
       }
   }
   ```
2. Copy all dependencies to the some place in the build directory

   ```
   task<Copy>("assembleJsLib") {
       configurations.compile.get().resolve().forEach { file: File ->
           from(zipTree(file.absolutePath), {
               includeEmptyDirs = false
               include { fileTreeElement ->
                   val path = fileTreeElement.path
                   (path.endsWith(".js") || path.endsWith(".js.map")) && (path.startsWith("META-INF/resources/") ||
                           !path.startsWith("META-INF/"))
               }
           })
       }
       from(tasks.withType<ProcessResources>().map { it.destinationDir })
       into("$buildDir/js")

       dependsOn("classes")
   }
   ```
3. Use the `com.moowork.node` plugin to run Webpack.

   ```
   import com.moowork.gradle.node.task.NodeTask

   plugins {
       id("kotlin2js") version "1.3.21"
       id("com.moowork.node") version "1.2.0"
   }

   node {
       download = true
   }

   task<NodeTask>("webpack") {
       dependsOn("npm_install")
       setScript(File("$projectDir/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack"))
   }
   ```
4. Make sure everthing is executed on `gradle build`

   ```
   tasks {
       named("webpack") { dependsOn("assembleJsLib") }
       assemble { dependsOn("webpack") }
   }
   ```
5. Create a minimal `package.json`for Npm.

   ```
   {
       "devDependencies": {
           "webpack": "^4.29.0",
           "webpack-cli": "^3.2.1"
       }
   }
   ```
6. Create a minimal `webpack.config.js`

   ```
   const path = require('path');

   module.exports = {
       mode: 'development',
       devtool: 'source-map',
       entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/classes/kotlin/main/kotlin-lib.js'),
       resolve: {
           "modules": [
               path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/js'),
               "node_modules"
           ]
       },
       output: {
           filename: "kotlin-lib.js",
           libraryTarget: "umd",
           path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/webpack'),
       }

   };
   ```